# Using Bayes' Theorem with three events

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, bayes-theorem

As a short seatwork in probability, we were given this problem but I am not exactly sure if we're supposed to use Bayes' Theorem for this one:

If you get to have a nap for at least `3` hours, then you can stay awake at midnight `80%` of the time. If you get `1-3` hours of nap, then you can stay awake at midnight `60%` of the time. Lastly, if you get `1` hour or less, then you can only stay awake at midnight `20%` of the time.

Let there be `10%` chance that you get to nap for at least `3` hours, `70%` chance to nap `1-3` hours, and `20%` chance to nap for at most `1` hour.

If you fell asleep through the whole night, what is the probability that you got to nap for at least `3` hours?

How do we solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some **hints**:

First formalize by defining events:

- $A$ - stays awake $\Rightarrow A'$ sleeps through
- $E_1$ - gets at most 1-hour nap
- $E_2$ - gets 1-3 hours nap
- $E_3$ - gets at least 3-hours nap

Now, the data given is:

- $P(E_1)=0.2$, $P(E_2)=0.7$, $P(E_3)=0.1$
- $P(A|E_1) = 0.2$, $P(A|E_2) = 0.6$, $P(A|E_3) = 0.8$

The question asks for

\begin{eqnarray*}P(E_3|A')
& = & \frac{P(E_3\cap  A')}{P(A')}\\
& = & \frac{P(E_3) - P(E_3\cap  A)}{1-P(A)} \\
& \stackrel{P(E_i \cap A)=P(A|E_i)P(E_i)}{=} & \frac{P(E_3) - P(A|E_3)P(E_3)}{1-\sum_{i=1}^3 P(A|E_i)P(E_i)}
\end{eqnarray*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll see what I can do with your hints.

Comment: $= \dfrac{0.1 - (0.8\cdot 0.1)}{1 - ((0.2\cdot 0.2) + (0.6\cdot 0.7) + (0.1\cdot 0.8))} \approx 0.043 = 4.3\%$  Is this the correct answer?

Comment: You just plug in the given probabilities and evaluate. But to do this I leave it up to you :-)